# I'm new to salesforce,can anyone help me to do child to parent query using wrapper class?I'm not able to get an output in my visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
public class WrapperDemoController{


   public class TableRow{
      public String Name{get;set;}
      public String Phone{get;set;}
   }


  set<id> AccountId= new set<id>();
  public  WrapperDemo(){ 
  for(Contact con : [SELECT Account.Name, Phone FROM Contact WHERE AccountID = :AccountId]){


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: share your VF code ?

Comment: You can use SObject relationship fields (such as `Account` in your example) directly in Visualforce. Wrapper classes are only needed where there isn't a SOQL populated relationship field or where you want to add an attribute such as a selected flag.

Answer (score 3):

An illustration of why to only introduce a wrapper class when it is needed...

Wrapper version:

```
public class WrapperDemoController {

    public class TableRow {
        public String name {get; set;}
        public String phone {get; set;}
        TableRow(String name, String phone) {
            this.name = name;
            this.phone = phone;
        }
    }

    public TableRow[] rows {get; set;}

    public WrapperDemoController() {

        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        accountIds.add(...);

        rows = new TableRow[] {};
        for (Contact c : [
                SELECT Account.Name, Phone
                FROM Contact
                WHERE AccountID in :accountIds
                ORDER BY Account.Name
                ]){
            rows.add(new TableRow(c.Account.Name, c.Phone));
        }
    }
}

<apex:pageBlockTable var="r" value="{!rows}">
    <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!r.name}"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Phone" value="{!r.phone}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Non-wrapper version:

```
public class DemoController {

    public Contact[] contacts {get; set;}

    public DemoController() {

        Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
        accountIds.add(...);

        contacts = [
                SELECT Account.Name, Phone
                FROM Contact
                WHERE AccountID in :accountIds
                ORDER BY Account.Name
                ];
    }
}

<apex:pageBlockTable var="c" value="{!contacts}">
    <apex:column value="{!c.Account.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!c.Phone}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to use a Wrapper class for this example. As Keith C said:

> Wrapper classes are only needed where there isn't a SOQL populated relationship field or where you want to add an attribute such as a selected flag.

Assuming we aren't seeing the bigger picture and you do need this functionality, you can take a look at [this Salesforce resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class). It's pretty well commented and explains exactly how to create a wrapper class. Assuming you don't need checkbox functionality, you could just modify the code appropriately.

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperClassController">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Process Selected" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="table"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <!-- In our table we are displaying the cContact records -->
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c" id="table">
        <apex:column >
          <!-- This is our selected Boolean property in our wrapper class -->
          <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!c.selected}"/>
          </apex:column>
        <!-- This is how we access the contact values within our cContact container/wrapper -->
        <apex:column value="{!c.con.Name}" />
        <apex:column value="{!c.con.Email}" />
        <apex:column value="{!c.con.Phone}" />
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class wrapperClassController {

  //Our collection of the class/wrapper objects cContact 
  public List<cContact> contactList {get; set;}

  //This method uses a simple SOQL query to return a List of Contacts
  public List<cContact> getContacts() {
      if(contactList == null) {
        contactList = new List<cContact>();
        for(Contact c: [select Id, Name, Email, Phone from Contact limit 10]) {
          // As each contact is processed we create a new cContact object and add it to the contactList
          contactList.add(new cContact(c));
      }
    }
    return contactList;
  }


  public PageReference processSelected() {

    //We create a new list of Contacts that we be populated only with Contacts if they are selected
    List<Contact> selectedContacts = new List<Contact>();

    //We will cycle through our list of cContacts and will check to see if the selected property is set to true, if it is we add the Contact to the selectedContacts list
    for(cContact cCon: getContacts()) {
      if(cCon.selected == true) {
        selectedContacts.add(cCon.con);
      }
    }

    // Now we have our list of selected contacts and can perform any type of logic we want, sending emails, updating a field on the Contact, etc
    System.debug('These are the selected Contacts...');
    for(Contact con: selectedContacts) {
      system.debug(con);
    }
    contactList=null; // we need this line if we performed a write operation  because getContacts gets a fresh list now
    return null;
  }


  // This is our wrapper/container class. A container class is a class, a data structure, or an abstract data type whose instances are collections of other objects. In this example a wrapper class contains both the standard salesforce object Contact and a Boolean value
  public class cContact {
    public Contact con {get; set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;}

    //This is the contructor method. When we create a new cContact object we pass a Contact that is set to the con property. We also set the selected value to false
    public cContact(Contact c) {
      con = c;
      selected = false;
    }
  }
}
```

I hate to just code dump, but at least this information is available elsewhere if needed.